# First Time Developing Web-Based Geographic Information System

Tags: web, gis

I'm assigned to develop web-based GIS, but I'm new with web programming. So, Where I can get an insight to start develop web-based GIS?

thank you before

regards!

Answer (score 1):

You have to know about the 2 main components for web programming: front-end and back-end.

Front-end, is how the results/graphics are going to be displayed in the client (pad, monitor). 
The most common tools are the javascript libraries like ArcGIS API for JavaScript, or OpenLayers.
For front-end you need to learn about html, css and javascript.

Back-end, is how you will manage the architecture (models-databases) of your project. There are many technologies to choose, for example, Java (J2EE) or .NET. For geodatabases there are systems like SQL server or PostGIS. Back-end is normally placed in the server.

In GIS you would also need a web mapping server (for sharing data, for instance), you can use GeoServer or ArcGIS for Server (commercial).

In my experience, I like to use django as back-end, this is a framework for web development using python (There are also many libraries for GIS using python which you can integrate). With django you can use a model-view-template controller to manage data to the web pages in a simple and fast way. Django has also a module called geodjango, to manage geodatabases, but not strong as GeoServer.

Answer (score 0):

Start with "Requirements". To understand what requirements is, please start with a book on software engineering.

Once you have the requirements, you need to "Design" - what tools/technologies/languages to use. If you are just beginning programming, you typically get a senior to do the design

Then you get to a task, such as rendering google maps on a web page, that can be answered in something like stackoverflow.